# C#: Globally alias a generic class name?

Tags: c#, alias

in some project we are using Generics, and we get a lot of lines like this:

```
Line<SomeTClass,SomeCClass> myLine =
           (Line<SomeTClass,SomeCClass>)LineFactory.CreateLine(...)
```

We can declare local alias, with `using X = Line<SomeTClass,SomeCClass>`.

Then we can write, `X myLine = (X)LineFactory.CreateLine(...)`.

We have a lot a combination of `<T,C>` but we often use the same. Is it possible de declare the using globally, so that we won't have to declare the alias in each file?

Comment: a combination of `var` and `LineFactory.CreateLine(..)` returning the right type would work as well - why do you have to cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such thing as a global alias.  What you can do is use type inference to simplify your declarations:

```
var myLine = (Line<SomeTClass, SomeCClass>)LineFactory.CreateLine(...);
```

and if that's not specific enough for the inference system, you can make the CreateLine() method generic to enforce it:

```
var myLine = LineFactory.CreateLine<Line<SomeTClass, SomeCClass>>(...);
```

and given the name of the LineFactory type, maybe even simplify it some more:

```
var myLine = LineFactory.CreateLine<SomeTClass, SomeCClass>(...);
```

This last option feels "right" to me in some way I can't fully articulate.  Just in case you need a little help, the method declaration would look like something this:

```
public static class LineFactory 
{
    public static Line<T,C> CreateLine<T,C>(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: ok... I have to cast, and can't use `var` because after that I want to access specific properties, depending on T and C.

Comment: @FrancoisB.: If you do cast that doesn't rule out using `var`

Comment: @Francois - var doesn't prevent you from accessing specific properties, ever.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot create a global alias.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by adding a file, for example `GlobalUsings.cs` with the following declaration:

```cs
global using X = Full.Namespace.Line<SomeTClass,SomeCClass>;
```

You can also add it to the top of an existing file in your project if that makes more sense.