# How to force one method on Razor ambiguous reference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, json.net

On one MVC 4 project, we have a lot of Pages.cshtml that receive a collection of Models (generally hundreds of rows), which we serialize as JSON via

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

The problem is that on some of those pages we are receiving an exception (*The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength*).

We know what is the reason and how to fix it. The thing is that I would like to create a similar `Json.Encode()` method (using Json.Net), so we do not need to modify all the `cshtml` pages. If I create a `Json.Encode()` method, Razor complains about ambiguous reference between `My.Namespace.Json` and `System.Web.Helpers.Json`.

Again, we know how to solve this by adding an alias on the page:

```
@using Json = My.Alias.Json
```

What I'm trying to do is to transparently instruct Razor to choose this alias for all the `cshtml` pages that uses this `Json.Encode`. The reason is that I want this to be transparent, so later if somebody adds a new page, automatically he will start to use our custom JSON implementation.

I think on `Views/Web.config` you can add namespaces and some configurations for Razor, but I don't see how to explicitly set the aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue, but as far as I know that's not possible. See e.g. this: [C#: Globally alias a generic class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577692/c-globally-alias-a-generic-class-name)

As an alternative you could create a helper method `Html.JsonEncode()` and teach, drill or entice everyone to use that.

If you make it also do the `Raw()` call and return `IHtmlString`, then you can do `@Html.JsonEncode(Model)` as opposed to `@Html.Raw(Html.JsonEncode(Model))` and before you know it everybody is a fan of your new method.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Unfortunately, my approach created some issues with cached assemblies... not sure why. Anyway, I applied your approach. Thanks for the tip!